# Issue evaluating integral of a noncommutative function in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, integral

I am trying to write the following code to calculate the integral of a non-commutative function `H(t) * tau_1` with respect to `tau_1`. However, the following code returns the error message:`Could not turn tau_1*H(t) into a fraction in tau_1.`

```
import sympy as sp

H = sp.Function('H',commutative=False)
tau_1= sp.symbols('tau_1', constant=True)

sp.Integral(H(t)*tau_1,tau_1).doit()
```

I expected `H(t)` to be factored out of the integral because it is independent of `tau_1`, and to get the final result `H(t)/2*(tau_1)**2`. Why doesn't the above code work, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean when you try and take an integral with respect to a constant? How is the integral result that you shared correct?

Comment: The same error message appears if I don't include the ```constant=true```. The final result may be a bit confusing because I have limits for the integral in the code, I will edit the initial question so that it is clearer.

Comment: I'm asking the question in general. I'm trying to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I am trying to use sympy to evaluate some integrals for me; H(t) is a non-commutative function (a matrix which I will later substitute in). ```t``` (and ```H(t)```) is independent of ```tau_1```, so the above integral should be easily evaluated. I am interested in more complicated expressions, but I believe the above is a minimum working example that reproduces the error. Perhaps I have to specify that ```H(t)``` is not a function of ```tau_1```?

Comment: Yes it does; I saw it earlier and couldn't make it work for sp.Integral (instead of sp.integrate, as in that other question). Adding the manual=true flag inside the doit, as in```sp.Integral(H(t)*tau_1,tau_1).doit(manual=True)``` does the trick. If you write it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks for your help!